# How to convert an HTML website with stylesheets to Drupal 7 nodes?

Tags: theming

I have a question. How can I convert a site with a few stylesheets.css file for the layout into Drupal 7. I'm not so worried about the content of the site, that is not so much. But I would like the layout to be converted to a drupal 7 theme. How can I do that whitout making a hole new theme my shelf. I'm just a beginner with Drupal and want a quick resulte.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for to avoid creating a whole theme from scratch is known as a [starter theme](http://drupal.org/node/323993).  Starter themes are special themes designed to *not* work as themes by themselves, only to be used as foundations for a theme you build on top of them (the latter is known in Drupal-speak as a sub-theme). I.e. starter themes are theme framworks that "reset" the CSS, so that you can rebuild the CSS without having to think about inherited styling.

Pick the starter theme that looks like it best suites your needs, and build on that.

As for stater themes: [Zen](https://drupal.org/project/zen) is the one that most people use. The other one I will recommend is [Basic](https://drupal.org/project/basic).  It is a stripped down fork of Zen. As a bonus, both are responsive by default.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Welcome to Drupal stackexchange

If you want to get started on theming.

You should Go after some of the famous base themes like Fusion, Zen, Omega

I see fusion as very easy.

[Fusion handbook](https://drupal.org/node/629408)

> Installing Fusion
>
> If you've ever installed a Drupal theme before, you'll find that
>   installing Fusion is just as easy. And if you haven't, don't worry:
>   You'll still be fine! There are five simple steps:
>
> Download the Skinr module (the 1.x branch, as of March 2010), which
>   gives you access to many of Fusion's unique features Download Fusion
>   Enable the Skinr module Enable and set a Fusion subtheme (such as
>   Acquia Prosper or the included Fusion Starter) as your site's default
>   theme Give yourself permission to access Skinr's controls If you’re
>   not the site's "super user" (that is, the person holding the first
>   account created when you installed Drupal), you (or someone with
>   sufficient permissions) need to explicitly allow you to use Skinr's
>   features. Go to the user permissions page (e.g.
>   http://www.example.com/admin/user/permissions), scroll down to the
>   "skinr module" section, and check all boxes under your user role.

Here is a how to in creating a [Fusion Sub theme](https://drupal.org/node/629454)